# In mysql: how can I select the most recently added row when selecting by MAX if two values are equal (application is a games high score table)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to construct a highscore table from entries in a table with the layout

```
id(int) | username(varchar) | score(int) | modified (timestamp)
```

selecting the highest scores per day for each user is working well using the following:

```
 SELECT id, username, MAX( score ) AS hiscore 
 FROM entries WHERE DATE( modified ) = CURDATE( )
```

Where I am stuck is that in some cases plays may achieve the same score multiple times in the same day, in which case I need to make sure that it is always the earliest one that is selected because 2 scores match will be the first to have reached that score who wins.

if my table contains the following:

```
   id   |     username      |    score   |       modified
________|___________________|____________|_____________________
    1   |     userA         |      22    | 2014-01-22 08:00:14
    2   |     userB         |      22    | 2014-01-22 12:26:06
    3   |     userA         |      22    | 2014-01-22 16:13:22
    4   |     userB         |      15    | 2014-01-22 18:49:01
```

The returned winning table in this case should be:

```
   id   |     username      |    score   |       modified
________|___________________|____________|_____________________
    1   |     userA         |      22    | 2014-01-22 08:00:14
    2   |     userB         |      22    | 2014-01-22 12:26:06
```

I tried to achieve this by adding `ORDER BY modified desc` to the query, but it always returns the later score.  I tried `ORDER BY modified asc` as well, but I got the same result

Answer (score 3):

This is the classic [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) problem, which has been answered frequently on StackOverflow. Here's a solution for your case:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM entries e
JOIN (
    SELECT DATE(modified) AS modified_date, MAX(score) AS score
    FROM entries
    GROUP BY modified_date 
) t ON DATE(e.modified) = t.modified_date AND e.score = t.score
WHERE DATE(e.modified) = CURDATE()
```

Comment: Ok, I get the idea, although using this statement as is results in an sql error: Unknown column 'e.modified_date' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 0):

I think this would works for you and is the simplest way:

```
SELECT username, MAX(score), MIN(modified) 
FROM entries 
GROUP BY username
```

This returns this in your case:

```
"userB";22;"2014-01-22 12:26:06"
"userA";22;"2014-01-22 08:00:14"
```

However, I think what you want (in your example would be wrong) the most recent row. To do it, you need this:

```
SELECT username, MAX(score), MAX(modified) 
FROM entries 
GROUP BY username
```

Which returns:

```
"userB";22;"2014-01-22 18:49:01"
"userA";22;"2014-01-22 16:13:22"
```